# Opposite indices when using find-function

Tags: matlab, matrix

i searched a lot in google but didnt find an answer that did help me without reducing my performance.

I have a Matrice A and B of the same size with different values. Then i want to filter:

1. `indices=find(A<5 & B>3)`

   - `A(indices)=`
   - `B(indices)=`
2. Now I want to apply a function on the indices -> `indices_2=find(A>=5 | b<=3)` **without** using the `find` function on the whole matrices `A` and `B` again. Logic operations are not possible in this case because I need the indices and not `0` and `1`.

Something like:

- `A(~indices)=`
- `B(~indices)=`

instead of:

```
indices_2=find(A>=5 | B<=3)
```

- `A(indices_2)=`
- `B(indices_2)=`

And after that I want to split these sets once again.... Just Filtering.

I used `indices_2=setdiff(indices, size(A))` but it did screw my computation performance. Is there any other method to split the matrices into subsets without using `find` twice?

Hope you understand my problem and it fits the regulations.

Comment: I don't understand how `setdiff(indices,size(A))` would help. If I understand your question correctly, `setdiff(1:numel(A),indices)` is what you would need? But I am not sure how that compares in terms of performance to using find twice

Comment: using find 6x times on A gives me  arond 500ms for my algorithm. Using setdiff instead makes !42seconds!.      I cant use logic on my matrice B,C,D (indices) because afterwards i need to search the reduced sets ->       indices_next=find(B(indices)<=4)

Comment: @kybnation why are you using `find` at all? Logical indexing is faster...

Comment: You may be able to make all the reduced sets first and then operate on them and aggregate results (or operate on combinations of them). Also, if you ask future questions where performance is relevant, please make sure to include (dummy) variable definitions as they allow timings to take place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why you can't just use `find` again, nor why you can't use logical indexing in this case but I suppose if you are going to restrict yourself like this then you could accomplish this using `setdiff`:

```
indices_2 = setdiff(1:numel(A), indices)
```

however, if you are worried about performance, you should be sticking to logical indexing:

```
indices = A<5 & B>3
A(indices)=...
B(indices)=...
A(~indices)=...
B(~indices)=...
```

Comment: I suppose I was was few seconds too slow :)

Comment: yeah i used to do that but how do i go on?@dan       indices_next=A(indices)<10  .....  A(indices(indices_next)) did not work in matlab

Comment: @kybnation that sounds like a different question. `indices_next`...?

Comment: i want to filter the found set of values A(indices).  - indices_next=find(A(indices)<9)  - A(indices(indices_next))=8    and after that i want again - indices_next_next=find(A(indices(indices_next)==10)       - A(indices(indices_next(indices_next_next)))=13

Comment: @kybnation that is a different question. Either edit this question or ask a new one (my answer currently answers your original question)

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be looking for something like this:

```
%Split your data in two and keep track of which numbers you have
ranks = 1:numel(A);
indices= find(A<5 & B>3);

% Update the numbers list to contain the set of numbers you are interested in
ranks_2 = ranks(~indices)

% Operate on the set you are interested in and find the relevant ranks
indices_2= A(~indices)>=5 | B(~indices)<=3
ranks_2 = ranks_2(indices_2)
```

Comment: but `ranks` is a scalar unless I'm missing something here?

Comment: @Dan Sorry, missed 2 characters. Has been corrected.

Comment: `~indices` is just a vector of `false` isn't it? Maybe you didn't intend on that first `find`?